# Need to find if the given variable is an instance or class

Tags: python, django

I have method which takes in a variable - `change_obj`. It can either be a function or a django instance. I try to find out if it is a function or a django instance using the below statement.

`obj_type = type(change_obj).__name__ #'function' or 'instance'`

`obj_type` was `Topo`. On debugging found that

```
(Pdb) type(change_obj)
<class 'applications.topo.models.Topo'>
```

I was expecting

```
<type 'instance'>
```

Interesting `dir(change_obj)` and `dir(type(change_obj))` have very similar outputs. I had tried the below in python prompt and got the below behavior which is different

```
>>> class Topo:
...    id = 123
...    name = 'T'
...
>>> t = Topo()
>>> type(t)
<type 'instance'>
```

Requirement - Given a variable need to find out if it is an instance or a method.
Stack - Py 2.6.8 and Django 1.3.5

Comment: why is it interesting that `dir(change_obj)` and `dir(type(change_obj))` have very similar outputs.. In fact it is obvious they should have the SAME ouput

Comment: When I tried the same in python prompt, I got the below:>>> class Topo:
...     id = 123
...     name = 'T'
...
>>> t = Topo()
>>> type(t)
<type 'instance'>

Comment: Can I ask what this method is supposed to be doing? it sounds like it may have underlying issues.. (i'd also strongly suggest upgrading your django, the version you are using is no longer supported)

Comment: I am logging events in save() method of certain select model classes. Similarly, I am logging the start and end of certain method calls. This will help in consolidating the saves done within a single method. I have one method to log these two types of data - function or instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example class `Topo` in the shell isn't very relevant. It is an [old style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), because it does not subclass `object`.

If you import the `Topo` model into your shell, you'll get the same result as in pdb.

```
>>> from applications.topo.models import Topo
>>> t = Topo()
>>> type(t)
<class 'applications.topo.models.Topo'>
```

If you want to check whether an object is a django model instance, I would use [`is_instance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
from django.db import models
t = Topo()
is_model = isinstance(t, models.model)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps and I will use this.